# make the footer responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a footer which is displaying correctly in desktop mode view of footer is

[image]

code for the footer is

```
 <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-footer col-md-4 col-xs-7">
                <ul class="no-list-style footer-navigate-section">
                    <li><a href="#">Join</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Order History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Write Review</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-footer col-md-4 col-xs-7">
                <ul class="no-list-style footer-navigate-section">
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">T&C</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-footer col-md-4 col-xs-7">
                <ul class="menuextras extras">


                    <li><a href="#"><img src="icons/facebook.png" height="30" width="30" ></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><b><img src="icons/twitter.png" height="30" width="30"></b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><b><img src="icons/linkedin.png" height="30" width="30"></b></a></li>


                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

when i try to make responsive its view is getting converted like this

[image]

i wish to retain the same design as it is in the first image in the responsive design also, can anyone tell how i can do it

Comment: You'll need to supply the CSS you're using too. I would suggest using the Code Snippet function.

Comment: Why did you have `col-xs-7` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7511/)**

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-footer col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <ul class="no-list-style footer-navigate-section">
                    <li><a href="#">Join</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Order History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Write Review</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-footer col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <ul class="no-list-style footer-navigate-section">
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">T&C</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-footer col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                <ul class="menuextras extras">


                    <li><a href="#"><img src="icons/facebook.png" height="30" width="30" ></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><b><img src="icons/twitter.png" height="30" width="30"></b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><b><img src="icons/linkedin.png" height="30" width="30"></b></a></li>


                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In xs-mode you have 3 colums with a width of 7 columns. Bootstrap have a 12 coloumn grid. Change that for example to col-xs-4 and all 3 divs would be side by side.